# Client IP is not preserved using Azure Application Gateway and Nginx ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, azure-application-gateway

I have an app which runs on AKS, using nginx ingress and is exposed through Azure Application Gateway.

When I access the app through the gateway, the client IP is replaced with the Application Gateway IP (showing into ingress logs).

I configured ingress with `--set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local`.

I tried to add a rewrite rule on the Gateway to force X-FORWARDED-FOR header with {var_client_ip} value.

What I have missed ?

Comment: Did you get any workaround so far? Have you used 'add_x_forwarded_for_proxy' variable?

Comment: Hi! Do you have an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the X-FORWARDED-FOR header won't change the ip adress. The Application Gateway, by nature, stops requests and starts them again at the application gateway, this means all requests going through an application gateway will get the IP address from the application gateway. This isn't something you can rewrite or spoof (and you should be glad it can't).

You have to trust the IP of the application gateway on your backend application. If you cannot trust on that alone, you can (as a combination with the gateway IP check) also pass the x-forward-for header with the originating client IP (as you already do) and validate that header in your backend application, in this case you're sure the XFF header isn't tempered with, since your requests are always coming from the application gateway, and that gateway rewrites all XFF headers with the client IP (which I assume for now).